# Google Chrome Icon Appears Twice on Taskbar After Launching Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, taskbar

I am running Windows 10, and there is an icon for Chrome on the taskbar.  Starting yesterday, whenever I click the icon to start Chrome a second Chrome icon appears on the taskbar.  Task Manager shows there is just one instance of Chrome running.

This problem started, I believe, after I created a new Chrome profile and then deleted that profile.  That resulted in my losing all my bookmarks and history, but I was able to recover those from a backup copy of the hard drive.

I don't mind having the two Chrome icons, but perhaps some settings are incorrect and I should re-install Chrome.  Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I have two active chrome profiles (work and private) and they occupy separate pinned taskbar items. It's been a while since I set this up, but it could definitely be that.

Comment: You created a new Windows profile or a new Chrome user profile?  Please [edit] your question to clarify your question.  Have you tried to remove the pinned shortcut and simply recreate it?

Comment: I edited the question as you suggested.  I un-pinned the Chrome shortcut on the taskbar so that no Chrome icon was there.  I then pinned it again from the icon in the Start Menu.  When I click it to launch Chrome a second  Chrome icon appears on the taskbar.  BTW, I noticed that Chrome bookmarks are now stored in: "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 2".  I wonder if that profile was created when I added/then deleted a profile yesterday.  I'm pretty confused about profiles and would prefer to have none (or one if that's the minimum).  Thanks.

Comment: Yes; It indeed was created when you created the new profile

Comment: I'm still wondering why a second Chrome icon appears on the taskbar when I start Chrome.  I don't mind it, but perhaps there is a settings or other issue that should be dealt with.